# The tz parameter in pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp()

Tags: apache-spark, timezone, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am currently working on time series data via Spark and dealing with timezones.

Some of the built in function of SparkSQL utilised a specific time zone parameters, for instance:

```
pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, tz)

Assumes given timestamp is UTC and converts to given timezone.

>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('1997-02-28 10:30:00',)], ['t'])
>>> df.select(from_utc_timestamp(df.t, "PST").alias('t')).collect()
[Row(t=datetime.datetime(1997, 2, 28, 2, 30))]
New in version 1.5.
```

Using time zone short hand may not be convenient in my case as the timezone information is stored in the format of "+01:00".

So my question is: **How can I incorporate the offset string in the format of "+01:00" into spark dataframe so that the offset is taken into account?**

Comment: Saying "the time zone problem" when talking about time is like saying "the pancreas problem" when talking about digestion.  It's an essential component, even if you don't understand it well. It's not really a *problem*, it's just that they exist.

Comment: You should probably read [the time zone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: Ok, Thanks.  Now, in the timezone tag wiki, read "time zone != offset" section, and perhaps you'll understand why passing `+01:00` is not appropriate.  Also, take a look at [some common time zone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) and you'll soon see that they too are not appropriate, due to ambiguities with abbreviations like `CST`.  Ultimately, you should be using IANA time zone identifiers, such as `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: @MattJohnson I understand that timezone is not equivalent to offsets. But in my situation I only have the offset information and need to modify the timestamp based on the offset.

Comment: Instead of copying function docstring which adds nothing here you should try to explain the exact problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks. Question updated.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want. Maybe the missing part is that Spark can parse ISO 8601 strings with an offset directly. Even if your data is not the exact format you can easily do something like this `CAST('1997-02-28T10:30:00+1:00' AS timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **GMT+01:00** as explained in 
[java.util.TimeZone doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)